# mouseover not working in ie6

Tags: javascript, css

I am using below code to call a `div` on hover,it is working fine on ie7+,ff and chrome, but not in ie6.

```
<div class="business-bottom-content" onMouseOver="javascript:this.className='business-bottom-content-hover';" onMouseOut="javascript:this.className='business-bottom-content'">
```

Comment: First step: Remove the `javascript:` from within the event codes

Comment: How important is it that it works on IE6? You are talking about a browser that was superceded five years ago so if you aren't working directly for a client that specifies it you could maybe just let the 10% stuck with it live without their mouseover.

Comment: @TJHeuvel Your comment could apply to every one of the 2,093,145 questions on this site.  Querying the different behaviour of ie6 an ie7, with the code snippet, seems a perfectly good question to me - although Ashutosh, you should try and accept a few answers to your previous questions.

Comment: What is "&gt;" in your example? Or in your original example: what is double "<" on forward. This DIV is closed properly? Add `alert(this.tagName)` into `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`, what displayed (if displayed)?

Comment: I'm confused. If all you're going to do is change the class name, I'd assume your changes can be done via CSS - so why not use the `:hover` psuedo-class for modern browsers, and use an ie6 fix like this? http://www.danvega.org/blog/2008/1/1/CSS-hover-selector

Comment: IE6 came out 10 years ago. Major websites have stopped supporting it. It's time to move on and pretend that IE6 no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it applies to `onMouseOver` as well, but `:hover` in CSS only works for `a` elements in IE6.

As for what you are trying to do, I would also recommend using `:hover` in CSS instead.